# Unable to build pthreads: undefined reference to 'zend_hash_index_insert'

Tags: php, compilation, pthreads

I've never really compiled PHP before so it might be really easy to fix, but googling the function title gives me no clue to what zend_hash_index_insert references to.

I get the following message:

```
ext/pthreads/src/.libs/store.o: In function `pthreads_store_chunk':
/var/php-custom/php-5.5.0/ext/pthreads/src/store.c:298: undefined reference to 'zend_hash_index_insert'`
```

I am configuring with

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-pthread --disable-cgi --with-readline --with-curl --with-openssl --enable-pthreads --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-maintainer-zts`
```

The entire command that make tries to (unsuccessfully) run is:

```
/bin/bash /var/php-custom/php-5.5.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=link /var/php-custom/php-5.5.0/meta_ccld -export-dynamic -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -R /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ext/date/php_date.lo ext/date/lib/astro.lo ext/date/lib/dow.lo ext/date/lib/parse_date.lo ext/date/lib/parse_tz.lo ext/date/lib/timelib.lo ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.lo ext/date/lib/unixtime2tm.lo ext/date/lib/parse_iso_intervals.lo ext/date/lib/interval.lo ext/ereg/ereg.lo ext/ereg/regex/regcomp.lo ext/ereg/regex/regexec.lo ext/ereg/regex/regerror.lo ext/ereg/regex/regfree.lo ext/libxml/libxml.lo ext/openssl/openssl.lo ext/openssl/xp_ssl.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_chartables.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_ucd.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_compile.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_config.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_exec.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_fullinfo.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_get.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_globals.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_maketables.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_newline.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_ord2utf8.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_refcount.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_study.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_tables.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_valid_utf8.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_version.lo ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_xclass.lo ext/pcre/php_pcre.lo ext/sqlite3/sqlite3.lo ext/sqlite3/libsqlite/sqlite3.lo ext/ctype/ctype.lo ext/curl/interface.lo ext/curl/multi.lo ext/curl/share.lo ext/curl/curl_file.lo ext/dom/php_dom.lo ext/dom/attr.lo ext/dom/document.lo ext/dom/domerrorhandler.lo ext/dom/domstringlist.lo ext/dom/domexception.lo ext/dom/namelist.lo ext/dom/processinginstruction.lo ext/dom/cdatasection.lo ext/dom/documentfragment.lo ext/dom/domimplementation.lo ext/dom/element.lo ext/dom/node.lo ext/dom/string_extend.lo ext/dom/characterdata.lo ext/dom/documenttype.lo ext/dom/domimplementationlist.lo ext/dom/entity.lo ext/dom/nodelist.lo ext/dom/text.lo ext/dom/comment.lo ext/dom/domconfiguration.lo ext/dom/domimplementationsource.lo ext/dom/entityreference.lo ext/dom/notation.lo ext/dom/xpath.lo ext/dom/dom_iterators.lo ext/dom/typeinfo.lo ext/dom/domerror.lo ext/dom/domlocator.lo ext/dom/namednodemap.lo ext/dom/userdatahandler.lo ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apptype.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/ascmagic.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/cdf.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/cdf_time.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/compress.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/encoding.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/fsmagic.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/funcs.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/is_tar.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/magic.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/print.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/readcdf.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/readelf.lo ext/fileinfo/libmagic/softmagic.lo ext/filter/filter.lo ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.lo ext/filter/logical_filters.lo ext/filter/callback_filter.lo ext/hash/hash.lo ext/hash/hash_md.lo ext/hash/hash_sha.lo ext/hash/hash_ripemd.lo ext/hash/hash_haval.lo ext/hash/hash_tiger.lo ext/hash/hash_gost.lo ext/hash/hash_snefru.lo ext/hash/hash_whirlpool.lo ext/hash/hash_adler32.lo ext/hash/hash_crc32.lo ext/hash/hash_fnv.lo ext/hash/hash_joaat.lo ext/iconv/iconv.lo ext/json/json.lo ext/json/utf8_decode.lo ext/json/JSON_parser.lo ext/pdo/pdo.lo ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.lo ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.lo ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.lo ext/pdo/pdo_sqlstate.lo ext/pdo_sqlite/pdo_sqlite.lo ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_driver.lo ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_statement.lo ext/phar/util.lo ext/phar/tar.lo ext/phar/zip.lo ext/phar/stream.lo ext/phar/func_interceptors.lo ext/phar/dirstream.lo ext/phar/phar.lo ext/phar/phar_object.lo ext/phar/phar_path_check.lo ext/posix/posix.lo ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.lo ext/pthreads/src/lock.lo ext/pthreads/src/globals.lo ext/pthreads/src/prepare.lo ext/pthreads/src/synchro.lo ext/pthreads/src/state.lo ext/pthreads/src/store.lo ext/pthreads/src/resources.lo ext/pthreads/src/modifiers.lo ext/pthreads/src/handlers.lo ext/pthreads/src/object.lo ext/readline/readline.lo ext/readline/readline_cli.lo ext/reflection/php_reflection.lo ext/session/mod_user_class.lo ext/session/session.lo ext/session/mod_files.lo ext/session/mod_mm.lo ext/session/mod_user.lo ext/simplexml/simplexml.lo ext/simplexml/sxe.lo ext/spl/php_spl.lo ext/spl/spl_functions.lo ext/spl/spl_engine.lo ext/spl/spl_iterators.lo ext/spl/spl_array.lo ext/spl/spl_directory.lo ext/spl/spl_exceptions.lo ext/spl/spl_observer.lo ext/spl/spl_dllist.lo ext/spl/spl_heap.lo ext/spl/spl_fixedarray.lo ext/standard/crypt_freesec.lo ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.lo ext/standard/crypt_sha512.lo ext/standard/crypt_sha256.lo ext/standard/php_crypt_r.lo ext/standard/array.lo ext/standard/base64.lo ext/standard/basic_functions.lo ext/standard/browscap.lo ext/standard/crc32.lo ext/standard/crypt.lo ext/standard/cyr_convert.lo ext/standard/datetime.lo ext/standard/dir.lo ext/standard/dl.lo ext/standard/dns.lo ext/standard/exec.lo ext/standard/file.lo ext/standard/filestat.lo ext/standard/flock_compat.lo ext/standard/formatted_print.lo ext/standard/fsock.lo ext/standard/head.lo ext/standard/html.lo ext/standard/image.lo ext/standard/info.lo ext/standard/iptc.lo ext/standard/lcg.lo ext/standard/link.lo ext/standard/mail.lo ext/standard/math.lo ext/standard/md5.lo ext/standard/metaphone.lo ext/standard/microtime.lo ext/standard/pack.lo ext/standard/pageinfo.lo ext/standard/quot_print.lo ext/standard/rand.lo ext/standard/soundex.lo ext/standard/string.lo ext/standard/scanf.lo ext/standard/syslog.lo ext/standard/type.lo ext/standard/uniqid.lo ext/standard/url.lo ext/standard/var.lo ext/standard/versioning.lo ext/standard/assert.lo ext/standard/strnatcmp.lo ext/standard/levenshtein.lo ext/standard/incomplete_class.lo ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.lo ext/standard/ftp_fopen_wrapper.lo ext/standard/http_fopen_wrapper.lo ext/standard/php_fopen_wrapper.lo ext/standard/credits.lo ext/standard/css.lo ext/standard/var_unserializer.lo ext/standard/ftok.lo ext/standard/sha1.lo ext/standard/user_filters.lo ext/standard/uuencode.lo ext/standard/filters.lo ext/standard/proc_open.lo ext/standard/streamsfuncs.lo ext/standard/http.lo ext/standard/password.lo ext/tokenizer/tokenizer.lo ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.lo ext/xml/xml.lo ext/xml/compat.lo ext/xmlreader/php_xmlreader.lo ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.lo TSRM/TSRM.lo TSRM/tsrm_strtok_r.lo TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.lo main/main.lo main/snprintf.lo main/spprintf.lo main/php_sprintf.lo main/fopen_wrappers.lo main/alloca.lo main/php_scandir.lo main/php_ini.lo main/SAPI.lo main/rfc1867.lo main/php_content_types.lo main/strlcpy.lo main/strlcat.lo main/mergesort.lo main/reentrancy.lo main/php_variables.lo main/php_ticks.lo main/network.lo main/php_open_temporary_file.lo main/output.lo main/getopt.lo main/streams/streams.lo main/streams/cast.lo main/streams/memory.lo main/streams/filter.lo main/streams/plain_wrapper.lo main/streams/userspace.lo main/streams/transports.lo main/streams/xp_socket.lo main/streams/mmap.lo main/streams/glob_wrapper.lo Zend/zend_language_parser.lo Zend/zend_language_scanner.lo Zend/zend_ini_parser.lo Zend/zend_ini_scanner.lo Zend/zend_alloc.lo Zend/zend_compile.lo Zend/zend_constants.lo Zend/zend_dynamic_array.lo Zend/zend_dtrace.lo Zend/zend_execute_API.lo Zend/zend_highlight.lo Zend/zend_llist.lo Zend/zend_opcode.lo Zend/zend_operators.lo Zend/zend_ptr_stack.lo Zend/zend_stack.lo Zend/zend_variables.lo Zend/zend.lo Zend/zend_API.lo Zend/zend_extensions.lo Zend/zend_hash.lo Zend/zend_list.lo Zend/zend_indent.lo Zend/zend_builtin_functions.lo Zend/zend_sprintf.lo Zend/zend_ini.lo Zend/zend_qsort.lo Zend/zend_multibyte.lo Zend/zend_ts_hash.lo Zend/zend_stream.lo Zend/zend_iterators.lo Zend/zend_interfaces.lo Zend/zend_exceptions.lo Zend/zend_strtod.lo Zend/zend_gc.lo Zend/zend_closures.lo Zend/zend_float.lo Zend/zend_string.lo Zend/zend_signal.lo Zend/zend_generators.lo Zend/zend_objects.lo Zend/zend_object_handlers.lo Zend/zend_objects_API.lo Zend/zend_default_classes.lo Zend/zend_execute.lo main/internal_functions_cli.lo sapi/cli/php_cli.lo sapi/cli/php_http_parser.lo sapi/cli/php_cli_server.lo sapi/cli/ps_title.lo sapi/cli/php_cli_process_title.lo -lcrypt -lresolv -lcrypt -lreadline -ltermcap -lrt -lcurl -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt  -o sapi/cli/php
```

Environment info:

```
ubuntu@root:~$ uname -a  
Linux 3.2.0-31-virtual #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:36:36 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
ubuntu@root:~$ gcc -v  
Using built-in specs.  
COLLECT_GCC=gcc  
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper  
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu  
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu  
Thread model: posix  
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

If any more details are required, please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been fixed in commit faf34f38731ef5fe050b4baba049aadbf7efedf6, please checkout master and try again.